# use mysql to update specific field(s) using expressjs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am developing a middleware using express.js with mysql(new to mysql) and in my situation I have built this patch method to update the table. but the issue is I dont want to pass the entire field set to update specific fields out of many. so whats the preferred way to do this so that whatever fields I will send in request body those fields should be updated only.

```
const updateCompany = (req, res, next) => {
  const cid = req.params.cid;

  const {
    company_id,
    company_name,
    company_address_line1,
    company_address_line2,
    company_email,
    company_phone,
    longitude,
    latitude
  } = req.body;

  var myquery = `UPDATE Company_Master SET company_name="${company_name}",company_address_line1="${company_address_line1}",company_address_line2="${company_address_line2}",company_email="${company_email}",company_phone="${company_phone}",longitude=${longitude},latitude=${latitude} WHERE company_id = "${cid}"`

    conn.query(myquery, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("err" + err);
      } else {
        res.status(201).json(req.body);
      }
    })

}
```

Comment: First of all, for security reasons you shouldn't add query parameters by string templates but use parameterized queries. Second, you will have to check if a value is contained in the body and add the respective `SET` clause to your query only then ... And finally, your route should also return a result to the client, if the query had an error. `if (err) { console.log(); res.sendStatus(400) }` as otherwise the client will run into a timeout while waiting for a response

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions its a rudimentary sort of function and I will be adding what you suggested as a practice but just wanted to solve the specific update issue.

Comment: why negative vote to my question I fail to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follows

```
const updateCompany = (req, res, next) => {
  const cid = req.params.cid;
  let 
    allowedcolumns = ["company_name", "company_address_line1",  ... ], //all columns that can be updated
    stmts = [],
    values = [];
    
  for (let c of allowedcolumns) {
      if (c in req.body) {  //check if there is a value for that column in the request body
          stmts.push(`${c} = ?`),
          values.push(req.body[c]);
      }
  }
  
  if (stmts.length == 0) {
      return res.sendStatus(204); //nothing to do
  }
  
  values.push(cid);
  conn.query(`UPDATE Company_Master SET ${stmts.join(", ")} WHERE company_id = ?`, values, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("err" + err);
      res.sendStatus(400);
    } else {
      res.status(200).json(req.body);
    }
  })
}
```

`allowedcolumns` will contain all columns that you are allowed to update via this request. For each of them check, whether there is a value in the request body or not. If yes, add it to the update statements, if not, ignore it (this assumes, the properties in the `req.body` and the columns in the table have the same name). Furthermore, to create a parameterized query, add the respective value to a `values` array, that you then can pass to the query.

If you don't have any values, there is nothing to do, so you can immediately return.

Else execute the query (don't forget to also add the `cid` to the values array). And return the respective status, based on whether there was an error or not.

BTW: 201 is status `CREATED`. You shouldn use that, if you are updating an already existing entity ...

Comment: Gosh it was amazing...thank you derpirsher for the awesome solution. It worked like a charm...

Comment: Just need to ask one thing i have tried this with wrong cid but its not showing any error means ID didnt match therefore row update failed...can i use result.affectedrow to check if any row affected or not and then show message accordingly?

Comment: No row matching your condition is not an error, therefore it won't report any error. But yes, you can use `result.affectedRows` or `result.changedRows` to determine how many rows were affected/changed. See the docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#getting-the-number-of-affected-rows for the differences between those two properties